# Node JS one to one Messages

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have made a Module in Node JS. In which I am pushing a Message from One user to another Using Different Web Browsers.

In CMD Console its working properly and message is sending. But it is not showing on Client Page.

Here is the CMD Output:

[image]

**Here is My Node Server Code:**

```
var app                 = require('http').createServer(),
    io                  = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs                  = require('fs'),
    mysql               = require('mysql'),
    connectionsArray    = [],
    connection          = mysql.createConnection({
        host        : 'localhost',
        user        : 'admin',
        password    : 'admin',
        database    : 'test',
        port        : 3306
    }),
    POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000,
    pollingTimer;

// If there is an error connecting to the database
connection.connect(function(err) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
  console.log( err );
});

// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
app.listen(8000);



/*
*
* HERE IT IS THE COOL PART
* This function loops on itself since there are sockets connected to the page
* sending the result of the database query after a constant interval
*
*/

var pollingLoop = function () {

    // Doing the database query
    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users'),
        users = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query

    // setting the query listeners
    query
    .on('error', function(err) {
        // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
        console.log( err );
        forwardMessage( err );
    })
    .on('result', function( user ) {
        // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
        users.push( user );
    })
    .on('end',function(){
        // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
        if(connectionsArray.length) {
            pollingTimer = setTimeout( pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL );

            //updateSockets({users:users});
        }
    });

};


// creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) 
{
    console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);
    // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
    if (!connectionsArray.length) 
    {
        //pollingLoop();
    }
    socket.on('addUser', function (id) 
    {
        socket.id   = id;   
        console.log('Here I am. My User ID is: '+socket.id);
        socket.emit( 'notification' , 'ok' );   
    });



    socket.on('disconnect', function () 
    {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf( socket );
        console.log('socket = ' + socketIndex + ' disconnected');
        if (socketIndex >= 0) 
        {
            connectionsArray.splice( socketIndex, 1 );
        }
    });






    socket.on('sendMessage', function (message) 
    {
        console.log( 'Wow I got a New Message:'+message+' sent by: '+socket.id );

        socket.emit( 'notification' , message );
        //insertion in db
        // get concerned ids to pass notification
        var users = new Array();

        users.push('777');

        // call forwardMessage to send notifications...
        forwardMessage(users,message);

    });


    console.log( 'A new socket is connected!' );

    connectionsArray.push( socket );

});






var forwardMessage = function ( users, message ) 
{
    connectionsArray.forEach(function( userSocket )
    {
        if(inArray(userSocket.id,users))
        {
            userSocket.volatile.emit( 'notification' , message );

        }
    });


    function inArray(needle, haystack) // In_Array Function For Javascript
    {
        var length = haystack.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
            if(haystack[i] == needle) 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**And here is my Client Code:**

```
<script>
        // create a new websocket

            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

            // on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
            socket.on('notification', function (data) 
            {
                //alert('got notification : '+data);
                $('#container').html('Got ');
            });


            socket.emit('addUser','<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>');






        //----------------- SEND MESSAGE FUNCTION -------------------------//

        function sendMESSAGE()
        {
            var message = $("#message").val();
            socket.emit('sendMessage',message);
        }

    </script>
```

**Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here or missing here ?**

Comment: what looks wrong to me, is that you use mysql in a way that makes no sense, i believe you underestimate the socket.io library, it should handle everything from connection handling to who is or isn't online..